# sqlite raw sql statement last n distinct rows

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a [simple database](https://github.com/tekija/LCd/blob/b963b050863c27270287a92f7e28d41c491eb862/wind.db?raw=true) and I want to filter out rows based on last n distinct values of one column.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///wind.db', echo=False)
table=engine.execute('SELECT DISTINCT time FROM wind')
```

I get time column:

```
('2021-04-12 00:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 01:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 02:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 03:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 04:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 05:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 06:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 07:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 08:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 09:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 10:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 11:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 12:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 13:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 14:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 15:00:00',)
('2021-04-12 16:00:00',)
```

Now I want to filter, lets say last 10 values from time column and apply that filtered column to filter database.
I tried with following to get filtered time column:

```
table=engine.execute('SELECT LAST 10 * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT time FROM wind)')
```

But no success so far.
How can I apply this query? I couldnt find any equivalent of TOP keyword in sqlalchemy documentation.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: That's great, but still haven't find TOP or FIRST, LAST keywords equivalent

Comment: `TOP` is MS Transact-SQL dialect specific. SQLite uses `LIMIT`, which is not standard SQL either, but a lot more common. Combined with `ORDER BY` you can get "top" results based on some order.

Comment: Thanks. LIMIT solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
table=engine.execute('SELECT * FROM wind WHERE time in ( SELECT DISTINCT time FROM wind ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 72 )')
```

This solved my problem.